# Check out button is not working on publishing pages on Blogs

Tags: 2013

"Check Out" button on Publishing Pages on the blog does not work.

There are no JavaScript errors in the console. Button just does not respond. However when I go to Pages library and check out the page, I return to the page and the same button is now "Check in and Save" and if I click the options beneath I can see the check out& edit and this works.

Does anyone have any idea why that might be happening? It does not happen on any other site, just on blogs. We are using a custom master page, but same master page is being used everywhere else too.

Comment: Does it work if you create a page from the browser?

Comment: I thought it did, as it works on other sites- but checking again it does not seem to work on ANY page in blog site template. I'll edit my question.

Comment: just to be sure, I think you should still try and check if the error is reproducible even when using a out-of-box masterpage. While it would be pretty odd, it is still possible that the custom masterpage is triggering an issue that only manifest when the site has some specific characteristics